# How to change EclipseLink in GlashFish 4.0?

Tags: jpa, netbeans, glassfish, eclipselink, glassfish-4

I want to change EclipseLink from 2.5.0 to 2.5.1 in GlashFish 4.0. I have [downloaded](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/) the [OSGi](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/rt/eclipselink/releases/2.5.1/eclipselink-plugins-2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5.zip) bundle and replaced the following jar files

1. org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar
2. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar
3. org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
4. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar
5. org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
6. org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar
7. javax.persistence.jar

under `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules`.

---

After doing this, the version still remains the same. The following code,

```
String version = org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersion();
System.out.println("EclipseLink version : " + version);
```

still displays the version 2.5.0.

---

The bundle contains no `eclipselink-x.x.x.jar`.

What else is required to be changed? I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot some files, you need the complete list:

1. org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar
2. org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
3. org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
4. org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.jar
5. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jar
6. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar
7. org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar
8. org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar
9. org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar
10. javax.persistence.jar

You don't have to rename the files, you can delete the old files starting with `org.eclipse` and copy the required files to the `modules` folder.
This should do the trick.

**Update**: If it doesn't work you may have to clear the OSGI cache. To do this shutdown the server and delete the folder `felix` in

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain/osgi-cache/
```

Restart the server and wait a moment, it'll have to read the OSGI module information to rebuild the cache.

Comment: I have replaced additional jars too but the version still remains stationary - 2.5.0.

Comment: I have renamed all of these jar files from, for example, `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5.jar` to `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar`.

Comment: Maybe you have to clear your OSGI cache, see my update.

Comment: Done as per the latest revision and I could see the version - 2.5.1. Thank you!

Comment: For me, it was enough to copy over `...asm`, `...core` and `...moxy`

Comment: Thank you. I did not change javax.persistence.jar